# How to resolve Shearing issue while rotating image in Adobe After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

I had an image in my After Effect Composition. I want to rotate the image by time with out any disorder in its shape.

When I am trying to rotate image a shearing effect is happening. How to resolve this issue, so that there will not be any shearing to image while rotating.

Below I have attached what happening now when I am trying to rotate.

1. Default Image : 0 degree rotation.
   [image]
2. Transformed image : 42 degree rotation.
   [image]

Comment: Scale is locked to proportional?

Comment: Even when scale values are locked and unlocked, I am getting same effect. Sorry I didn't checked before commenting. I will update my screen shots with scaling options settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure `scale` values are locked and set both to **100%**:

[image]

Comment: This is it. Scale Default size in locked state, then rotate. Thanks. Lots of confusion in-between. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is that composition a 16:9 composition with non-square pixels? looks like it. Check your composition settings, particularly the **[pixel aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio)** setting.

[image]

If your pixel aspect ratio is not **Sqare Pixels** then the comp is set up to display correctly only when it is stretched. This is the way DV video and DVDs do 16:9 while still having the same pixel resolution as 4:3 video. When you render and play it in a player there is metadata in the file that tells the player to play back with the stretching, so that it looks ok. But AE displays it without the stretching unless you turn on **Pixel Aspect Ratio Correction**.

You can turn **Pixel Aspect Ratio Correction** on in the composition display window with the little icon at the bottom of the composition window

[image]

or from the menu **View > View Options…**

[image]

What it looks you're doing is stretching the individual elements in the comp to make them look right. This won't work if you then render out with non-square pixels, or as you've noticed if you rotate them.

Comment: My Pixel Aspect Ratio is HDV 1080/DVCPRO HD 720 (1.33)
And, Frame Aspect Ratio is 16:9 (1.78).

I cant able to find out the icon in composition window to make Pixel Aspect Ratio Correction, so I tried with menu, in menu the view>view options is in disabled state now.How can I activate this option.

Comment: You have to have the composition window open and active (the blue border should be around it). Just click somewhere in the composition window to activate it.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that this usually happens to me because at least one layer that other objects are parented to has a scale value (X,Y) that doesn't match. Deselect all your layers, press "S" to open the scale value of all your layers, and look for one whose X and Y values do not match (i.e 100,75.4). Correct that and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Gary - please read existing answers before posting. The top answer was already accepted and confirmed as correct by the OP.